# force output on a MAX3232 RS-232 transceiver

Tags: rs232, transceiver, max3232

I need to probe the output RX (DOUT1/2) nets (connected to one MCU's UART) of a MAX3232 RS232 transceiver, for this I'll use the PCB test points, but I'd also like to "force" logic levels on the RX outputs of the transceiver (suppose no TX inputs when this happens) using the probe. Is this possible without damaging the transceiver?

Comment: The datasheet gives unlimited short-circuit duration for T1OUT, T2OUT but doesn't for R1OUT, R2OUT. If you're worried then add a 1k series resistor between RxOUT and the UART input and test point.

Answer (score 1):

You can't short push-pull logic outputs together.

Just drive the receiver input with a voltage waveform you want to have the receiver output with a voltage waveform you want.